# whether plural or singular when a sentence starts with 'one of the

Tags: grammar

one of the reputed universities' or 'one of the reputed university' which is correct?
 whether plural or singular

one of the reputed universities' or 'one of the reputed university' which is correct?

Answer (score 1):

**one of the reputed universities'**

In reference to one of the many reputed universities (Plural).

one of the reputed university, is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

‘One of the reputed universities’ is correct.

Expressions beginning ‘one of’ are usually followed by a plural noun and a singular verb.

Example:
One of my friends is going to Zambia. (NOT One of my friend are going to Zambia.)